# Converting string to datetime year converts the year in the milliseconds position

Tags: python, date, datetime

Trying to convert a year column in a pandas dataframe from string to dateformat (year), and I get something like this:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001920    
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001930    
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001910    
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001925    
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001899
```

I dont know why all values are taking "1970" as year. The vales I want to have land in the milliseconds.. What I need actually is just the year in this format YYYY and the values should be the ones above 1920, 1930, 1910 etc..

Here is the code I use to convert the column:

```
properties_no_na['year_built'] = pd.to_datetime(properties_no_na['year_built'])
```

How to get just the 1920, 1930, 1910 values which are now landing in milliseconds instead of in year place?

This code returns "True" 
    from pandas.api.types import is_string_dtype
    from pandas.api.types import is_numeric_dtype

```
print(is_numeric_dtype(properties_no_na['year_built']))
```

So 'year_built' is a numeric column..

[image: year_built column screenshot]

Comment: Share the `year_built` column (or a sample of it).

Comment: done! Edited question

Comment: Oh ok. You mean that your input is a year? How about: `pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Y', errors='coerce')`?

Comment: Tried it now like this: properties_no_na['year_built'] = properties_no_na['year_built'].to_datetime(s, format='%Y', errors='coerce') and got this exception: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: it should look like this: `properties_no_na['year_built'] = pd.to_datetime(properties_no_na['year_built'], format='%Y', errors='coerce')`

Comment: Tried it like you said and I get dates like this: 1924-01-01 --> All the years are added 01-01 for the 1st January. I tried then to add a line of code after the code you proposed which is this one: properties_no_na['year_built'] =properties_no_na['year_built'].dt.year  and then I get 1924.0 or 1970.0 (how to get just "1924" or just "1970" without that '.0' and as a dateformat? Any ideas to get rid of it? Thanks a lot btw!

Comment: Well I'm missing what you are trying to achieve. If you convert any time format to `datetime` you will have a date and a timestamp.

Comment: Okay. So no way to have just the year for ex. '1924' as value and not '1924.0'?

Comment: Sorry but isnt that what you have already? I am confused. You could do `.dt.year.astype(int)` to give you an int. But no 'nan'-values are allowed.